# Setting a value if not null within a java stream

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

How can I handle `null` checks in the below code using Java 8 when my counterparty can be `null`. 
I want to set `counterParty` only if it has a value and not set if it is empty.

```
 public static Iterable<? extends Trade> buildTrade (final List<Trade> trade) {
    return () -> trade.stream()
                .map(trade -> Trade.newBuilder()
                    .setType(trade.type())              
                    .setUnit(trade.unit())
                    .setCounterParty(trade.counterParty())                  
                    .build())
                .iterator();
    }
```

Comment: override `setCounterParty()` method in `Trade` class

Comment: What's the default value for `counterParty` in the builder? Does it even make a difference if you just set it to `null`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
trade.stream()
            .map(trade -> {
                TradeBuilder tb = Trade.newBuilder()
                    .setType(trade.type())              
                    .setUnit(trade.unit());
                Optional.ofNullable(trade.counterParty())
                    .ifPresent(tb::setCounterParty);
                return tb.build();
             })
            .iterator();
```

Or without `Optional`:

```
trade.stream()
            .map(trade -> {
                TradeBuilder tb = Trade.newBuilder()
                    .setType(trade.type())              
                    .setUnit(trade.unit());
                if(trade.counterParty() != null) tb.setCounterParty(trade.counterParty());
                return tb.build();
             })
            .iterator();
```

Comment: Works fine, but argument against using `Optional.ofNullable()` then unwrapping it in the same code block, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41632128/7512

Comment: @slim thanks for the comment, I've shared alternative version without using `Optional`

Answer (score 0):

The stream aspect of this has no relevance to the question; let's strip it out:

```
 trade -> Trade.newBuilder()
    .setType(trade.type())              
    .setUnit(trade.unit())
    .setCounterParty(trade.counterParty())                  
    .build()
```

You're asking to not set `counterParty` if it is null.

A really easy way to do this would be to modify builder class's `setCounterParty()` to do nothing and return, if the parameter is null.

```
TradeBuilder setCounterParty(CounterParty cp) {
   if(cp != null) {
      this.counterParty = cp;
   }
   return this;
}
```

You do need to ensure that this behaviour is consistent with other callers' needs.

If your builder is being dynamically generated by some framework (Lombok etc), you might not have code in which you can easily make this change -- but most such frameworks have mechanisms that allow you to take control of that kind of thing.

If you can't modify the builder, you can break up the calls to it, and surround
one call with an `if`:

```
 trade -> { 
    TradeBuilder b = Trade.newBuilder()
      .setType(trade.type())              
      .setUnit(trade.unit());
    if(trade.counterParty() != null) {
      b.setCounterParty(trade.counterParty());
    }
    return b.build()
 }
```